# Proper multirow export in Pandas to latex

Tags: python, pandas, latex

I have the following problem.
Have a dataframe looking like this

| Technology | Metric | Endpoint | Value |
| ---------- | ------ | -------- | ----- |
| A          | A      | A        | 1     |
|   A        | A      | B        |  3    |
|  A         | B      |    A     |    3  |
|  A         |  B     |   B      |  5    |
...

I want to export it using df.to_latex() so that it look like this

| Technology | Metric | Endpoint | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A | A | 1 |
|  |  | B | 3 |
|  | B | A | 3 |
|  |  | B | 5 |

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use multiindexing here:

```
df.set_index(['Technology', 'Metric', 'Endpoint'], inplace=True)
```

So pandas will automatically group the 'Technology' and 'Metric' levels